# R shiny Warning: Error in &&: 'length = 3' in coercion to 'logical(1)'

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, coercion

**Update:**

The error is occuring specifically when the shiny app tries to add the `shinyalert` pop-up, which has three elements (this is what the `length = 3` refers to in the error). If I remove the HTML line, the error changes to `length = 2` and If I omit all of the below lines I don't get the error (but they are needed for the rest of the app to work):

```
  observeEvent(input$map_click, {
    
    shinyalert(html = TRUE, showConfirmButton = F,
               text = tagList(HTML(paste0("Proposition :<br>")), 
                              textInput("prop", ""),
                              actionButton("enter", "Valider")))
  })
```

I am therefore reasonably sure that it is the `shinyalert` package which is at issue and the `if` statement relates to whether the map was clicked or not.

---

I am developing a shiny app to allow users to drop-pin on a map and label the points, then export them in a .csv.  The app was already described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75676691/r-shiny-leaflet-extract-latitude-longitude-and-label-of-markers-to-a-dataframe/75685651#75685651) and a working solution was provided for my original problem.

However, when I try to run the solution having recently upgraded R to 4.3.0 (and updated the required packages), I get the following error:

```
Warning: Error in &&: 'length = 3' in coercion to 'logical(1)'
  3: runApp
  2: print.shiny.appobj
  1: <Anonymous>
```

The error occurs when I try to click on the map in the shiny app to register a GPS point.

I have read a few other posts and github issues on this error, and as far as I understand, it is a  recent change in base R (I think) which is having the knock-on effect of generating this error under certain circumstances in multiple r packages.

However, I have not been able to find a list of the affected packages, so don't know which of the ones I am using here is throwing the error.  I have seen posts (with no responses yet) with this error for other shiny apps, so it could be shiny itself, but I'm not sure and don't know how to isolate it.

I also don't understand what the error means or how to fix it.  Can anyone help?

Here is my session info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.3.0 (2023-04-21 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)

Matrix products: default


locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.utf8   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.utf8    

time zone: Europe/London
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] sf_1.0-12        dplyr_1.1.2      rio_0.5.29       here_1.0.1       pacman_0.5.1    
[6] leaflet_2.1.2    DT_0.28          shinyalert_3.0.0 shiny_1.7.4     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] xfun_0.39             bslib_0.4.2           htmlwidgets_1.6.2     vctrs_0.6.2          
 [5] tools_4.3.0           crosstalk_1.2.0       generics_0.1.3        curl_5.0.0           
 [9] tibble_3.2.1          proxy_0.4-27          fansi_1.0.4           pkgconfig_2.0.3      
[13] KernSmooth_2.23-20    data.table_1.14.8     checkmate_2.2.0       readxl_1.4.2         
[17] uuid_1.1-0            lifecycle_1.0.3       compiler_4.3.0        fontawesome_0.5.1    
[21] httpuv_1.6.9          htmltools_0.5.5       class_7.3-21          sass_0.4.6           
[25] yaml_2.3.7            later_1.3.0           pillar_1.9.0          crayon_1.5.2         
[29] jquerylib_0.1.4       ellipsis_0.3.2        classInt_0.4-9        cachem_1.0.8         
[33] mime_0.12             zip_2.3.0             tidyselect_1.2.0      shinydisconnect_0.1.0
[37] digest_0.6.31         stringi_1.7.12        colourpicker_1.2.0    forcats_1.0.0        
[41] rprojroot_2.0.3       fastmap_1.1.1         grid_4.3.0            cli_3.6.1            
[45] magrittr_2.0.3        utf8_1.2.3            e1071_1.7-13          foreign_0.8-84       
[49] withr_2.5.0           promises_1.2.0.1      backports_1.4.1       cellranger_1.1.0     
[53] hms_1.1.3             openxlsx_4.2.5.2      memoise_2.0.1         knitr_1.42           
[57] haven_2.5.2           miniUI_0.1.1.1        rlang_1.1.0           Rcpp_1.0.10          
[61] xtable_1.8-4          glue_1.6.2            DBI_1.1.3             rstudioapi_0.14      
[65] jsonlite_1.8.4        R6_2.5.1              units_0.8-1
```

Comment: Are you using `&&` in your code? The stack trace seems to imply the problem is in your application code and not in some package code. The error means you are trying to do something like `c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE) && TRUE` which returns that error rather than just comparing two values like `TRUE && TRUE`

Comment: No I'm not using `&&` anywhere in my code - this is why it is confusing me, I think the double ampersand must be in some package function that I am using?  You can see the code in the answer to the post I linked.

Comment: I suggest you start with a minimal shiny app with none of your attached packages (other than `shiny`), then add in each one at a time to see if/when you can reproduce the error. It seems possible that one of them has not sufficiently guarded against R-4.3's change to error when `if (..)` is of length greater than one.

Comment: I can't replicate the error. I tested with `shiny_1.7.2` `DT_0.26` and `leaflet_2.1.2`.

Comment: Also the action that generates the error is ```observeEventinput$map_click, {
    
    shinyalert(html = TRUE, showConfirmButton = F,
               text = tagList(HTML(paste0("Proposition :<br>")), 
                              textInput("prop", ""),
                              actionButton("enter", "Valider")))
  })```

Comment: @r2evans the error seems to be linked to the `shinyalert` package, but I was able to run the example from that package without problems. The `shinyalert` does contain three elements, so maybe it is treating them like components of an ìf` statement?

Comment: It wasn't clear from your question that you were running the `shinyalert` version. That's why it's always better to to include the exact code you are running in the question itself so it's self-contained and clear. You can get around the error by collapsing the `text=` data yourself using `as.character()`. Use `text = as.character(tagList(HTML(paste0("Proposition :<br>")), textInput("prop", ""), actionButton("enter", "Valider"))))`

Comment: A little judicious commenting of various parts of your code indicates that the warnoing is generated by your call to `shinyalert`.  Moreover the `n` in Error in &&: 'length = `n`' varies according to the number of elements in your `tagList` call. You are generating your  `text` in a way analagous to the example in the online doc, so this looks to be like a bug in the `shinyalert` package.  I suggest you raise an issue with the developers.

Comment: I confirm @MrFlick's workaround works for me.  But I think it it is still raising the issue with the developers of `shinyalert` as your usage conforms to their sample code.

Comment: (@Limey, I think it needs other care, too ... the docs suggest including `useShinyalert()` in the `ui` section, and the app now says one does not need to call that anymore ... but it does not work. By using `useShinyalert(force=TRUE)` the sample app now works. Buglets to be fixed.)

Comment: new bug report has been filed: https://github.com/daattali/shinyalert/issues/76

Comment: This is a bug I already filled and it was already fixed in the development version.

Comment: I just saw that, thanks @StéphaneLaurent